# Use MVC Html.BeginForm with GET method and action parameters

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, razor

I know I can use Html.BeginForm to POST with action parameters like this:

```
@using (Html.BeginForm("Details", "Home", new { name = Model.Name }))
```

and I can GET like this:

```
@using (Html.BeginForm("Details", "Home", FormMethod.Get))
```

But I can't seem to do both.  How do I?

### Update

Here is the entirety of the form in question:

```
@using (Html.BeginForm("Details", "Home", new { name = Model.Name }))
{
    <div style="text-align: center">
        @Html.DropDownList("viewMonth", 
                                  new List<SelectListItem>(ViewBag.MonthNames))
        @Html.TextBox("viewYear", Model.ViewYear, new {style = "width: 30px"})
        <input type="submit" value="Go"/>
        <br/>
        <br/>
    </div>
}
```

where `viewMonth` and `viewYear` are parameter names in Action/Details.  If I try

```
@using (Html.BeginForm("Details", "Home", new { name = Model.Name }, 
                        FormMethod.Get))
```

it will pass viewMonth and viewYear, but not name.

Comment: You want to GET and POST in one form?

Comment: No, pardon my excellent communication.  I am trying to GET and use action parameters (which I suppose are RouteValues) in one form.

Answer (score 8):

> But I can't seem to do both

You can do both ... you can use the [`overload`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd492719) you need

So for example if `name` is a `routeValue`:

```
@using (Html.BeginForm("Details", "Home", new { name = Model.Name }, 
                        FormMethod.Get))
```

and if name is an `htmlAttribute` of the form:

```
@using (Html.BeginForm("Details", "Home", FormMethod.Get, 
                        new { name = Model.Name }))
```

and if you want to use both routeValues and htmlAttributes:

```
@using (Html.BeginForm("Details", "Home", new { name = Model.Name }, 
                        FormMethod.Get, new { name = "foo_bar" }))
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply.  I suppose name is a routeValue, since I intend it to be an action parameter, but the first code segment ironically enough will pick up two other routeValues from the ViewData but omit name.